# How to get correct price based on quantity in list using Cakephp2.x?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a listing page where I got item name,price,quantity.Now,I want if someone increase the quantity of item from list then price also increase according th actual price.Here is my file view_item.ctp

```
<?php
  foreach($result as $k=>$v) { ?>

  <tr class="hide_me_<?php echo $v['Inventory']['id']; ?> ">
  <td><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></td>
  <td><?php echo $v['Inventory']['item_name']; ?></td>
  <td class="text-center">
  <span class="box-plush" id='plusbutton' onclick="itemQty(<?php echo 
   $v['Inventory']['id']; ?>,'incr')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>

  <span class="box-dgt" id='att_<?php echo $v['Inventory']['id']; ?
  >'>1</span> 

 <span class="box-minus" id='minusbutton' onclick="itemQty(<?php echo 
 $v['Inventory']['id']; ?>,'decr')"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> </span> 
 </td>

 <td class="text-center" id='price_<?php echo $v['Inventory']['id']; ?>'><?
 php echo $v['Inventory']['item_price']; ?></td>

 <td class="text-right"><?php echo  $v['Inventory']['item_price']; ?></td>

 <td class="text-center">
     <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm close-box" href="javascript:void(0)" 
     onclick="menuItem(<?php echo $v['Inventory']['id']; ?>)">
      <i class="fa fa-times" ></i>
     </a> 
 </td>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   function menuItem(id){
   $('.hide_me_'+id).hide();
 }


  function itemQty(id,action){
    var qty = $('#att_'+id).text();
    qty = parseInt(qty);

  if(action=="incr"){
    $qty1 = qty+1;
  }else{
    $qty1 = qty-1;
  }  

    $('#att_'+id).text($qty1);
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: anyone please help me

Comment: My suggestion, use a [spinner (like this)](https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/) and then use event to calculate the price.

Comment: OR you can do like this https://jsfiddle.net/shahonseven/mmpsvb2y/4/

Comment: i didn' understandt can u explain

Comment: which one u did not understand? my first comment or second?

Comment: can edit my code plsss

Comment: second one is good but i am unable to implement

Comment: in your code, replace `.text()` with `.html()`

Comment: i replace now what i do?

Comment: edit js code accoeding to view_item.ctp if it is possible to u?

Comment: Ok, this is modified from your code, https://jsfiddle.net/shahonseven/gn8sees8/

I have to tweak few lines to get it to work

Comment: sir my code is not working

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace `onclick="itemQty(<?php echo $v['Inventory']['id']; ?>,'decr')"` with `data-row="<?php echo $v['Inventory']['id']; ?>"`

add `id="total_<?php echo  $v['Inventory']['item_price']; ?>`

to this line
`<td class="text-right"><?php echo  $v['Inventory']['item_price']; ?></td>`

so it becomes `<td class="text-right" id="total_<?php echo  $v['Inventory']['item_price']; ?>"><?php echo  $v['Inventory']['item_price']; ?></td>`

modify your itemQty function to calculate price

```
function itemQty(id, action) {
    let qty = $('#att_' + id).html();
    qty = parseInt(qty);

    if (action == "incr") {
      qty++;
    } else {
      qty--;
    }

    $('#att_' + id).html(qty);

    let price = parseFloat($('#price_' + id).html());
    let total = price * qty;
    $('#total_' + id).html(total.toFixed(2))
  }
```

and then add this lines at the bottom

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#plusbutton').on('click', function() {
      itemQty($(this).data('row'), 'incr')
    })

    $('#minusbutton').on('click', function() {
      itemQty($(this).data('row'), 'decr')
    })
  })
```

demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/shahonseven/gn8sees8/

Comment: please sir first u set up my .ctp file form start and show me

Comment: i am so confuse

Comment: the link I give u IS taken from your view.ctp, I just replace `<?php echo  $v['Inventory']['item_price']; ?>` with number 1

Comment: you can reach me at shahonseven [at] gmail

Comment: sir plss save my job

Comment: you can email me at shahonseven [at] gmail.com